# Multiple Visualizations with Howler.js

Tags: howler.js

I have multiple tracks playing simultaneously and I want to show each tracks volume level independently in the form of a volume meter.

I have the visualization working from the Master Gain within Howler, but I am unsure of how to connect an analyser to each separate track.

I currently have the following:

```
// Create analyzer
const analyser = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();

// Connect master gain to analyzer
Howler.masterGain.connect(analyser);

// Connect analyzer to destination
analyser.connect(Howler.ctx.destination);
```

What I would like would be something like the following:

```
let track1 = new Howl({
    src: ['track-1.mp3']
});

let track2 = new Howl({
    src: ['track-2.mp3']
});


// Create analyzer Track 1
const analyserTrack1 = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();

// Connect Track 1 to analyser
track1.gain.connect(analyserTrack1);

// Create analyzer Track 2
const analyserTrack2 = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();

// Connect Track 2 to analyser
track2.gain.connect(analyserTrack2);
```

All examples I have found only reference using the Master Gain. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't connect the analyzer to the destination this will cause sound issues as you loop the output back to the input. You can remove the following lines completely:
```// Connect analyzer to destination
analyser.connect(Howler.ctx.destination);```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by directly connecting the node:

```js
let track1 = new Howl({
    src: ['track-1.mp3']
});

let track2 = new Howl({
    src: ['track-2.mp3']
});


// Create analyzer Track 1
const analyserTrack1 = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();

// Connect Track 1 to analyser
track1._sounds[0]._node.connect(analyserTrack1);

// Create analyzer Track 2
const analyserTrack2 = Howler.ctx.createAnalyser();

// Connect Track 2 to analyser
track2._sounds[0]._node.connect(analyserTrack2);
```